# How to sum up the value from previous row to subsequent rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with the below specs

```
  | ID |  Name| count  |
  | -- |----  | ----   | 
  | 1  |  A   |  75    |
  | 2  |  B   |  10    |
  | 3  |  A   |  15    |
  | 4  |  A   |  10    |
  | 5  |  A   |  5     |
  | 6  |  A   |  3     |
```

If I set the threshold for the count to be 15, I want the below rows to get added up uniformly. So the output should be

```
  | ID |  Name |  count |
  | -- |----   | ----   | 
  | 1  |  A    |    15  |
  | 2  |  B    |    10  |
  | 3  |  A    |    30  |
  | 4  |  A    |    25  |
  | 5  |  A    |    20  |
  | 6  |  A    |    18  |
```

75 from ID 1 gets added up based on group "Name" and it is always based on threshold value. Please advice

Comment: besides the threshold, I didn't understand how the numbers in the final output got "added up uniformly"

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest thats what I wanted to achieve... group by Name, this 75 gets split up below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can do something like:

```
def distribute(sr, thres=15):
    idxmax = sr.idxmax()
    remain = max((sr[idxmax] - thres) / max(len(sr) - 1, 1), 0)
    return np.where(sr.index == idxmax, min(sr[idxmax], thres), sr + remain)

df['newcount'] = df.groupby('Name')['count'].transform(distribute, thres=15)
```

Output:

| ID | Name | count | newcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 75 | 15 |
| 2 | B | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | A | 15 | 30 |
| 4 | A | 10 | 25 |
| 5 | A | 5 | 20 |
| 6 | A | 3 | 18 |